# CUPS localhost webpage returning 404

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, printing

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with a Brother Printer. Worked fine for months but now is very unstable.

CUPS seems to have stopped working completely. Reinstall of the printer now fails. When I navigate to http://localhost:631 I can connect but any link I click returns an HTTP 404.

CUPS process is running.

Any clues as to what is going on with CUPS?

Comment: use `https://locahost:631`

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling CUPS?  `sudo apt install --reinstall cups`

Comment: @Terrance - Reinstall fixed it and my general printer problems. I did this to myself when I uninstalled imagemagick. I realized this as I watched the cups reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling CUPS fixed my issue. `sudo apt install --reinstall cups`

Thanks @Terrance.